# How to hide a message after few seconds in Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, postdelayed

I display a message notification to a user and hide that notification after few seconds and I'm using postDelayed() to achieve this functionality but the problem is when I update the notification with new message before hiding the first one, I need to reset/restart the timer. I couldn't find any way to achieve that as removeCallbacks() removes only the pending tasks.

Everytime I have new message to show on button click, I call `showNotification()` from `MyClass` with new message. Now, if I click the button again within 4 seconds (let's say `x` seconds) (before hiding the old notification message). There's no way to cancel the old postDelayed or restart the timer to 4 seconds and it hides my new notification after `4-x` seconds.

**MyClass.java**

```
...
// On Button Click - everytime a different message

MyNotification obj = new MyNotification();
obj.showNotification(msg);
...
```

**MyNotification.java**

```
public class MyNotification
{
    ...
    ...
    private static TextView textview1;
    private static MyNotification notification;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate()
    {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        notification = (MyNotification) this.findViewById(R.id.notification_bar);
        textview1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview_notification);
    }

    Runnable hideNotification = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textview1.setVisibility(GONE);
            notification.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    };

    public void showNotification(String msg)
    {

        textview1.setText(msg);
        textview1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        notification.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        // Hide Toast notification after few secs
        notification.postDelayed(hideNotification, 4000);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Handlers and add or remove callbacks as needed. I wrote a class for this. I will share with you.

```
   /**
     * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
     * User: App Studio 35
     * Date: 5/17/13
     * Time: 1:53 PM
     * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
     */

    public class TimeOutWatcher {

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MEMBERS
    *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private ITimeOutWatcher mTimeOutHandler = null;
    private Handler mHandler = null;
    private long mTimeOutMilliseconds;


    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Runnable
    *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private Runnable mTimeoutRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //If stopTimeOutWatch has not been called then trigger TimeOutOccurred
            if(mTimeOutHandler != null){
                mTimeOutHandler.TimeOutOccurred();
            }

            //Remove callback to avoid duplicate triggers
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimeoutRunnable);
        }
    };


   /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // METHODS
   *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Set TimeOutListener to trigger when timeout occurs
     *
     * @param listener of type ITimeOutWatcher
     */
    public void setTimeOutListener(ITimeOutWatcher listener){
        mTimeOutHandler = listener;
    }
    /**
     * Called when needing a timeout to occur based on the passed number of
     * Milliseconds. Performs a postDelay to trigger calling of TimeOutOccurred.
     * Must call stopTimeOutWatch after your waiting process is complete and
     * before this delay trigger happens if you want to avoid
     * getting a TimeOutOccurred
     *
     * @param timeOutMilliseconds
     */
    public void startTimeOutWatch(long timeOutMilliseconds){
        mTimeOutMilliseconds = timeOutMilliseconds;
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimeoutRunnable, timeOutMilliseconds);
    }
    public void resetTimeOutWatch(long timeOutMilliseconds){
        stopTimeOutWatch();
        startTimeOutWatch(timeOutMilliseconds);
    }
    public void resetTimeOutWatch(){
        stopTimeOutWatch();
        startTimeOutWatch(mTimeOutMilliseconds);
    }
    /**
     * Used to cancel TimeOut from happening
     * Call when process that you are waiting on is complete
     * to avoid TimeOutOccurred
     */
    public void stopTimeOutWatch(){
        if(mTimeoutRunnable != null){
            if(mHandler != null){
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimeoutRunnable);
            }
        }
    }


    public interface ITimeOutWatcher {

        /**
         * Called when TimeOutWatcher exceeds requested TimeOut Period
         */
        void TimeOutOccurred();

    }
}
```

usage is simple just create an instance of your TimeOutWatcher and start timeout for desired time. If you need to cancel it then call stop if you want to reset then call reset. Simple. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm one thing..
1. Is it gonna run the `Runnable` on same UI thread or gonna create a new thread. because my `Runnable` method modifies the existing UI element.

Comment: Yes, that is the Looper.prepareMainLooper() command in the handler new up. You can also modify this to remove that and run on whatever thread called it if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to prevent duplicate notifications if the button is clicked while a notification is already showing.

This is easily done by checking the visibility of the views before starting the runnable:

```
public void showNotification(String msg)
    {

        if (textview1.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            textview1.setText(msg);
            textview1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            notification.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

            // Hide Toast notification after few secs
            notification.postDelayed(hideNotification, 4000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As suggested by you, I'll have to update the code to only set the new text message if it's already visible. then again, I need a way to reset the timer to new 4 seconds and cancel the old timer (created on first time)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can cancel the runnable and post a new one: use [View.removeCallbacks(Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)).

So I think your code would change to :

```
public void showNotification(String msg)
{

    textview1.setText(msg);
    textview1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    notification.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    // Remove the existing hide instruction
    notification.removeCallbacks(hideNotification);
    // Hide Toast notification after few secs
    notification.postDelayed(hideNotification, 4000);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but this doesn't cancel the callbacks (as mentioned in my description), all previous `hideNotification` is no longer in `Pending` queue and is in `Running` queue and will eventually run after 4 seconds.